# How to change the favicon in Blazor webassembly app?

Tags: razor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a blazor app and I need to change the title and the favicon of the app, I could change the title successfully but the favicon it's not working, I am using mudblazor, [image: declearing the head elements using mudblazor][image: Page title working but favicon just not shown up]
while inspecting the page I can see that it's reading the html element and I am sure about the icon directory but still not working[image: Inspect page on chrome]

Tried to modify the index.html in the wwwroot but did'nt work

Comment: Please do not post images of source code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try href="favicon.ico"

Comment: it returned the default blazor favicon

Comment: oh it worked I had to try from another browser

Comment: You can replace favicon.ico file with the file of your choice,  can mark my solution as answer to help others

Comment: Use a browser private mode to check or clear the cached images