# How to change favicon.ico in a blazor app?

Tags: blazor

How to change favicon.ico in a blazor app?
I use

```
<head> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon2.ico" />
</head>
```

but do not see the new icon.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default Icon, follow [this](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/124) and perhaps comment on that issue, as its the same one that you are having

Comment: Done but no changes. Btw, I do it in _Host.cshtml

Comment: @ZedZip try setting the `base` see my edit

Comment: otherwise [read this](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-project-structure/)

Comment: My piece of code <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>AppWizard</title>
    <base href="~/" />
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

Comment: I use Electron.NET + Blazor for building Cross-platform Desktop application, may be there is  the reason...

Comment: @ZedZip see my edit

Comment: I have added my issue to the list https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/700

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690171/how-to-change-the-favicon-in-blazor-webassembly-app/71690408#71690408

Comment: I use Blazor+Electron.NET. Finally, I have made it the code using path to icon in appsettings.json. Thank you all!